# Model and Edmx binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on on an MVC application and i am making use of the entity framework .

what i am not able to figure out is whenever View is being created through Model class, in the controller it is getting binded directly with tables whereas in this scenario it should get binded with Model.

Kindly share some info on the same .

Comment: Show us some code that you think is incorrect.

Comment: How can you bind to tables in an MVC controller? What kind of tables? We want code!